# when mouseover on username display popup views

Tags: 7, views, users, ajax, theming

How to display popup ajax information of user when user mouseover on username or picture of users with views.
i want fetch information from profile user with ajax no hidden.
such as Facebook or LinkedIn

Comment: Any particular reason you want it in ajax, not just hidden and shown when needed?

Comment: @Mołot yes i show when in need

Comment: I would create a custom module which loads the user profile with a specific view mode when hovering the username. You would need PHP and Javascript for that. **UPDATE: I put it into a [sandbox](https://drupal.org/sandbox/yan_nick/2038805) on drupal.org.**

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question at hand :-/

Comment: May you expand your answer? As it is, it is not much helpful for the OP or future readers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hope this will help you

In Drupal 7, for your requirement you can use **[qTip (Stylish jQuery Tooltips)](https://drupal.org/project/qtip)** module with **Views**.

- After installing and configuring qTip, go through the qtip examples(refer **qtip README.txt**).
- For this example I have created a view with some user fields, these fields will popup on hovering user picture
- Create a new view and add fields which you want to show on the popup.
  [image]
- For showing user information in popup, you need to give the proper structure(read qtip README.txt).
- I have added the HTML structure for **profile_image** view field

  [image]
- On mouse hover of the user picture, user information will popup. And make **CSS** changes as per your requirement.
- You can also refer [BeautyTips](https://drupal.org/project/beautytips), for example you can refer this [link](http://www.lullabot.com/files/bt/bt-latest/DEMO/index.html)

Drupal 7 : Ajax load

Steps

- To show user details on hover you need to add attributes to the username, it can be done using preprocess function [template_preprocess_username](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_username/7) in your active theme tempalte file.
   
  `function themeName_preprocess_username(&$variables) {
    $variables['attributes_array'] = array('class' => array("user-info"), 'data-uid' => $variables['account']->uid);//adding more attributes for your requirement
  }`
- Create a view with the fields you want to show on popup.
- Create a menu to get user details like get/user_details/%, where % is the user-id. This menu will returns user details.

  `function test_menu() {
  ...
  $items['get/user_details/%'] = array(
  'title' => t(''),
  'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  'page callback' => 'get_user_details_ajax_callback',
  'page arguments' => array(2),
  'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  );
  ...
  return $items;
  }
  //Implement the ajax callback to get user details
  function get_user_details_ajax_callback ($uid) {
  $html = '';
  $html = views_embed_view('VIEWNAME','display_id', $uid);
  return $html;
  }`
- For showing the user details on hover, you need to make a ajax call using 
  $.ajax
- Once the user hover the username get the **data-uid attribute** and make a ajax call to get user info.
- Once you get the user details append it and show as popup.

  `Drupal.behaviors.getUserDetails = {
      attach: function (context, settings) {
        var replace_wrapper = 'user-'+$(this).attr('data-uid')+'details';
        //add html to show user details
        $( "a.user-info" ).each(function( index ) {
          if(!$(this).closest('div').hasClass('user-details-wrapper')){`

  ```
        $(this).append("<div class='user-details-wrapper'><div class'"+replace_wrapper+"'></div></div>");
      }
    });
    $('a.user-info').mouseenter(function(){
      if($(replace_wrapper).is(':empty')){//if empty then make ajax call and
        var url = Drupal.settings.basePath + 'get/user_info/'+ $(this).attr('data-uid');
        $.ajax({
          url: url,
          type: 'GET',
          success: function (data) {
            //create html and append to replace_wrapper
            var user_detail_html = '';
            //code to get user html here
            $(replace_wrapper).each(function( index ) {
              $(this).html(user_detail_html);
            });
          }
        });
      }else{
        //show popup here
        $('user-details-wrapper').show();
      }
    }).mouseleave(function() {
      //hide popup here
      $('user-details-wrapper').hide();
    });
   }
  }
  ```
- Make changes as per your requirement

  Note : [views_embed_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7#comment-32858)

Comment: thank you for answering i want to ajax load. i want in my site anywhere is show username not only when with views filed username

Comment: @reza I have update my answer for ajax load.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new path in a custom module.

```
function MODULE_menu() {
  $items['get/profile/%/ID'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'get_info',
    'page arguments' => array('$nid', 1),
    // …
  );
}
```

In your page callback use the following code.

```
function  get_info($nid) {
  $userInfo = user_load($nid);

  // Create your HTML.

  return $output;
}
```

When the user is hovering the mouse on the username, you make an AJAX call to that URL.

```
 $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "<?php echo url('get/profile'); ?>/"+NID,
   async: false,
   cache: false,
   timeout: 30000,
   success: function(resp) {
     $('popUp').html(resp);
   }
 });
```

I don't need to create a view for that, but if you need to use it you can create a view and in your page callback use the following code.

```
function  get_info($nid) {
  views_embed_view('VIEWNAME');
  return $output;
}
```

Comment: do you test your solution!?

Comment: yes, just create a new module and use hook_menu to create a new path with params, so you can get NID to get client's info with user_load().

Answer (score 0):

I found this sandbox module from October 2012 that might be helpful: https://drupal.org/sandbox/zeet/1801738:

> simple module to display the users profile information in popup balloon

Comment: The linked sandbox is empty. Try my sandbox instead – https://drupal.org/sandbox/yan_nick/2038805