# Flag content once seen in a slideshow

Tags: flags, javascript

Is there a way with either flags or rules or another module to make content being displayed in a slideshow flagged/marked as "viewed"? Then on refresh that content wouldn't display again to that user. Functionality of swiping for the mobile experience is key here. Think of it as a simplified tinder functionality.

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't. This is quite the unique use case, which will require custom code.

Comment: (a) Who or what is "*tinder*"? (b) Is the slideshow created using Views? (c) If a slideshow has (eg) 10 sides, and after viewing (eg) 3 of those slides, what should happen to the other 7 slides? (d) is this about Drupal 5, or any release above that?

Comment: a) Tinder is a dating app in which you swipe left or right to indicate that you are interesting in someone or not.

b) Slideshow is created using views

c) You'd still be able to view the other 7 slides, upon refreshing the page the slides that you have seen should no longer display.

d) Drupal 7 all the way

Answer (score 1):

I think [No Sssweat comment](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/212794/flag-content-once-seen-in-a-slideshow/212839#comment260029_212794) is right in that this requires custom code.. And you should include some extra details regarding Pierre's questions.

Assuming that you want it like Tinder, I think triggering a hidden flag on each node for each swipe event could be the easiest option. Then on refresh, a views filter would hide flagged content by that user.

[This answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/129255/53677) describes a method for doing similar. I haven't tested it myself yet but it's an accepted answer and quite recent so it should still work.

It's hard to give a more thorough answer for this without knowing more about the slideshow. And my jQuery is rudimentary at best. If this is a viable approach, post some more details and hopefully myself or another user can help with getting the event. If not, I'll remove this.

Comment: Your assumption is correct. Hidden flag on each node, when swiped it marks it as flagged. On refresh the filters would then hide any flagged nodes.

The other link that you mentioned could also work, seems close to what I'm looking for. I'm looking for a little less code, but I'm not affraid to get my hands dirty.